# TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function _inherits

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am getting this error:

> Super expression must either be null or a function

in the following code snippet:

```
import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';
const DB = SQLite.openDatabase('Data.db');

class Database {
    db;
    constructor(db) {
        this.db = db;
    }
    executeSql = (sql, params = []) =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.db.transaction((trans) => {
                trans.executeSql(
                    sql,
                    params,
                    (db, results) => {
                        resolve(results);
                    },
                    (error) => {
                        reject(error);
                    }
                );
            });
        });
}
export default new Database(DB);
```

```
import Database from '../db';
export class Note extends Database {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    all = () => async() => {
        console.log('all');
        const result = await DB.executeSql('Notes', ['params']);
        console.log('result', result);
    };
}

export default new Note();
```

Where is my mistake and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You probably need to fix the export of the first file.

Comment: Instead of export default new Database(DB), you need to export the class Database. You can only extend a Class, and not an instantiated Class object.

Comment: yes, i have tried it, but i want to use DB object:(

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you are trying to create a Class (`Note`) that extends another Class (`Database`), but the imported `Database` object in the second file is **not** a Class, but an instantiated Class object.

You don't need to extend the Database, (and you can't, since it's not a Class). You just need to import and use the method directly.

```js
import Database from '../db';
export class Note {

    constructor() {
    }

    all = () => async() => {
        console.log('all');
        const result = await Database.executeSql('Notes', ['params']);
        console.log('result', result);
    };
}

export default new Note();
```